# How to print the length of the absolute pathname of the current directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, cygwin

I'm the first time with Linux and having trouble.
How can I print the length of the absolute pathname of the current directory?
I tried to use wc, but it is for characters in a file not the path.

Comment: Try pwd command, it will give you present working directory

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `printf $(pwd) | wc -m`

You should use `printf` (instead of `echo`, since it adds another character `\n`), evaluate the return of the command `pwd` (print working directory), and then pipe it to `wc` with the `-m` flag which count characters

Edit: Thanks to Jon answer, `printf $(pwd)` won't print the full path if it contains a space. (his point is about escaped characters but I can't find an example ¯_(ツ)_/¯)

```
# tested on WSL
/my/path $ mkdir another\ dir
/my/path $ cd another\ dir
/my/path/another dir $ pwd
                    => /my/path/another dir
/my/path/another dir $ printf $(pwd)
                    => /my/path/another
```

Comment: You're welcome. In case you don't know yet, the `man` command and search engines can provide answers to most of your questions. Also, make sure to mark answers as "Solutions" if they solved your problem / fully answer your question; and upvote meaningful answers

Comment: Just to note `printf $(pwd)` will behave unexpectedly if the filename contains, for example, backslash characters, which are special to `printf`

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, you can calculate the answer using `pwd` and `wc`, subtracting 1 to account for the terminating newline

```
absolute_path_length=$(( $(pwd | wc -m) - 1 ))
```